# DPDK TX checksum offload for TCP has fixed offset from correct checksum

Tags: tcp, checksum, dpdk

I try to compute checksum for IP and TCP via DPDK checksum offload. The code does the following:

```c
ipv4_hdr->hdr_checksum = 0;
mb->l2_len = eth_hdr_len;
mb->l3_len = ipv4_hdr_len;
mb->ol_flags = PKT_TX_IPV4 | PKT_TX_IP_CKSUM | PKT_TX_TCP_CKSUM;
tcp_hdr->cksum = rte_ipv4_phdr_cksum(ipv4_hdr, mb->ol_flags);
```

rte_eth_conf has been set:

```c
port_conf.txmode.offloads = DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM | DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_CKSUM;
```

the IP checksum is right, **TCP checksum has fixed offset from the correct checksum** (under my environment, it is 4)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the answer [DPDK HW and SW checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755041/dpdk-hw-offloaded-calculation-of-udp-checksum-not-working/62777421#62777421). For enabling HW checksum one has to set the current checksum value to `0`.

```
/* HW check sum */ 
ip_hdr->hdr_checksum = 0; 
tcp_hdr = (struct tcp_hdr *)((char *)ip_hdr + info->l3_len);
tcp_hdr->cksum = 0;
```